# Creating a cdf from drawing balls from an urn

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that a subset of two balls is randomly chosen (without replacement) from an urn containing $5$ balls, numbered $1$ through $5$. Letting $Y$ denote the larger of the two numbers drawn, give the cdf of $Y$, being sure to give a value for $F_{Y}(y)$ for all real numbers).

**Attempted solution:**

There are $5\choose2$ possibilities. $(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)$. These numbers could also be flipped, but by symmetry, I can ignore them.

Out of these, $1$ never wins, $2$ wins once, $3$ wins twice, $4$ wins thrice, and $5$ wins four times. This gives probabilities of $0$, $1\over10$, $2\over10$, $3\over{10}$, and $4\over{10}$, respectively. Then,

$$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} {1} & \text{$y \geq 5$} \\ \frac{6}{10} & \text{$4 \leq y \lt 5$} \\ \frac{3}{10} & \text{$3 \leq y \lt 4$} \\{\frac{1}{10}} & \text{$2 \leq y \lt 3$}\\{0} & \text{$y \lt 2$}\end{cases}$$

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Looks good! Is there something you're nervous about?

Comment: Thanks! No, I just wanted to make sure I'm understanding cdf's correctly.

Comment: Assuming that every draw of two marbles is equally probable, it seems your probabilities are correct. And, as long as you interpreted $F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)$ (which it seems you did from your answer), then your interpretation is correct. Also, if you graphed your function, you'll notice that the gap distance of the jump between each point $y \in \{2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ is equal to the probability of $Y$ equaling that value.